# DB Design: How to connect two intermediate tables i.e. product-sales and product-modifiers

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, e-commerce, erd

[image: ERD]

I have three entities: *Product*, *Product-Sale-Orders* (i.e. orders), *Modifiers*  (Orange background color in ERD)

As *Product* and *Modifiers* have many to many relationship, so they would be linked by an intermediate table *Product-Modifiers*.
Similarly, *Product* and *Product-Sale-Orders* have many to many relationship, so they would be linked by an intermediate table *Product-Sales*
(Yellow background color in ERD)

**Now, how to link *Product-Sales* with *Modifiers*?**

Is the table *Product-Sales-Modifier* (pink background color in ERD) at correct place by linking *Product-Sales* and *Modifiers* OR it should link *Product-Sales* with *Product-Modifiers*

Now, if the design is not correct why is it so. And if it is then if a customer wants to repeat an order, all the product modifiers will be repeated as it is. So, **how will I get to know if the modifier is still active on the product or not**.

```
 Select * from Product-Sales 
    LEFT JOIN Product-Sales-Modifiers ON psm_psafk=psa_pk
    **LEFT JOIN Product-Modifiers ON pm_prdfk = psa_prdfk AND pm_modfk = psm_modfk** 
    WHERE psa_psofk = 1
```

That left join with Product-Modidfiers seems unnecessarily complicated. Do I need to store pm_pk too. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your naming convention, I understand that `psm_psafk` refers to  `psa_pk` and `psm_modfk` to `mod_pk` and I assume that `Xyz_pk` is a surrogate key that uniquely identifies a row in the table/entity.

In this case, `Product-Sales-Modifier` is at the (right) place that corresponds to its content, since it links `Product-Sales` and `Modifiers`.  If you would like to have it related to `Product-Sales` and `Product-Modifiers`,  you should use `psm_pmfk` instead of `psm_modfk`.

However, there is a subtle issue because  `Product-Sales-Modifier`  might allow to link `Product-Sales` to modifiers that are not related to any product used in the sales. The reason is that the systematic use of surrogate keys makes every relation independent from the others. The complex query with extra joins addresses this: it just makes sure that the data is consistent,  by not only simply join the product sales with the product sales modifier with the modifier,  but also restrict the mofifiers to those that are relevant to the right products (`ON pm_prdfk = psa_prdfk`).